# Reusable MaterialUi Dialog in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build a reusable Dialog for my React project.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
    return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

export default function AlertDialogSlide(data.show) {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  
    const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };
  
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          TransitionComponent={Transition}
          keepMounted
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">{data.title}</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
              {data.message}
            </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
              Close
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
}
```

My idea is to use the data variable to pass the arguments that I want to use in this reusable component: show: true or false, title: the dialog title and message: the dialog message.

How can I call this function `AlertDialogSlide` in another react component?

Thanks

Comment: You are receiving the `data` prop incorrectly, it should be `function AlertDialogSlide({ data })`. Then you use `data.open` like how you used `data.title` and `data.message`.

Comment: @bertdida Thank you, I fixed it, but how can I call AlertDialogSlide method inside another component?